# Vuejs date picker not displaying anything

Tags: vue.js, datetime, datepicker, vue-component, vue-router

I've tried to use vuejs persian date picker, but when I do as told in the readme it keeps displaying nothing! even all the other codes in that form wont show.
my date picker is:
[VuePersianDatetimePicker cdn](https://github.com/talkhabi/vue-persian-datetime-picker)
can anyone help please?
in Component:

```
import VuePersianDatetimePicker from 'vue-persian-datetime-picker'
export default {
  name: 'GetUserInput',
  data(){
    return {
      date: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    datePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
  }
}
<template><date-picker v-model="date"></date-picker></template>
```

in index.html :

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment-jalaali@0.7.4/build/moment-jalaali.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-persian-datetime-picker/dist/vue-persian-datetime-picker-browser.js"></script>
```

also installed the package.

[image: a series of my errors are:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here an working example of how you can use `VuePersianDatetimePicker` using CDN

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        date: '1400/04/05'
    },
    components: {
        DatePicker: VuePersianDatetimePicker
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment-jalaali@0.7.4/build/moment-jalaali.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-persian-datetime-picker/dist/vue-persian-datetime-picker-browser.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <p>selected date is: {{ date }}</p>
    <date-picker v-model="date"></date-picker>
</div>
```